# Using 2 nodes in the output sigmoid activation function for 2 mutually exclusive classes is somehow giving good results than softmax

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, classification, softmax

I know for two mutually exclusive classes softmax is the best activation function in the output layer. However, somehow (2, softmax) and even (1,sigmoid) are giving average results and (2, sigmoid) as output layer is giving excellent results (in terms of validation and test set accuracy).

But, as per my understanding, using (2, sigmoid) in the output layer for mutually exclusive classes is not logically correct. I don't understand why in my case (2,sigmoid) is giving better results than (2, softmax). Have any one encountered similar results?

Also, an interesting observation is that my two mutually exclusive classes are very complex. i.e., although they are mutually exclusive but its very difficult to put them in any of the classes in the training data and there will be some instances where it could have been any of the two. Would (2,sigmoid) be justified given the complexity of the classes ?

Comment: What do you mean with "better results"? Validation accuracy? Validation loss? Training loss?

Comment: With better results I meant better accuracy on validation and test sets.

Comment: The model will see the encoding of Y as feedback. How is that done? If it is not _0(Zero)_ for all except one then definitely _(Sigmoid, N)_ will work better.

Comment: The Y encoding is zero for all except one.

Comment: Can we say since an instance could be any of the two classes, then the instance could be both? In that case, they are not mutually exclusive per instance, thus performance of 2-sigmoid is justified.

Comment: Actually, we cannot say that they are not mutually exclusive, because an instance can only have one label at a time. However, we can definitely say that the labels in the training dataset are noisy and are not perfectly reliable (this is mainly because of the complexity of the classes).